# Running a python script on C# not working

Tags: c#, python, cmd

I have this code that I'm trying to run a Python script. It works correctly when I do it manually via the command prompt but if I try to do it via a button click in a C# Windows form it doesn't work.

```
private void btnGenerateAndrowarn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Android Tools\androwarn\Samples", "*.apk");
  foreach (string fileName in filePaths) {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
    Process process;
    string directory = @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Android Tools\androwarn\";
    string script = "androwarn.py";
    startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("python");
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = directory;
    startInfo.Arguments = directory + script + " -i " + fileName + " -r html -v 3";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What actually goes wrong?

Comment: the script dosn't run at all it should be generating something in my Report folders but nothing happens. If i do it manually it works and generates something in the Report folder.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your Output window of Visual Studio when it runs?

Comment: nope no errors at all only these System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that `python` is not in your %PATH%.

Comment: I added it into my %PATH%, like i said when i do it manually via cmd it works when typing "python"

Comment: But is it in you path when you launch the C# program?

Comment: Yes it is in the path of my C# program in bin/Debug